# Setting width inside of a flex row div

Tags: css

I have the following css:

```
#app {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                align-items: center;
                gap: 10px;
                padding: 20px;
                margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
                max-height: 400px;
                max-width: 400px;
                overflow-y: scroll;
            }
            .result {
                font-weight: 300;
                width: 400px;
                padding: 20px;
                text-align: center;
                background: #eceef0;
                border-radius: 10px;
            }
```

With this CSS I create the following:
[image]

This is scrolls from left to right.  The issue I'm having is that I can't enlarge the individual width of .result.  The max-width of the parent is 500px which would be the parent window and I'd like the child element to be 400px but it doesn't work.  It appears that the flex some how limits it.  Here is a code pen.

https://codepen.io/impactcolor/pen/VwXPNLe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you wanna change the `.result` box to 400px, if so you can try this

```css
.result {
+++ flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

this is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmD1f.png)

#app is a flex container, the items will behave in shrink. so you need to rewrite flex-shrink

> The items do not stretch on the main dimension, but can shrink.

you can find more information in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

My English is very basic, Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can set [`min-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width) to 400px inside the `.result` class. See following code:

```js
const {
  ref,
  createApp
} = Vue;
const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    let comments = ref([]);
    let page = 1;
    const load = async $state => {
      console.log("loading...");
      try {
        const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?_limit=10&_page=" + page);
        const json = await response.json();
        if (json.length < 10) $state.complete();
        else {
          comments.value.push(...json);
          $state.loaded();
        }
        page++;
      } catch (error) {
        $state.error();
      }
    };

    return {
      load,
      comments,
      page,
    };
  },
});
app.component("infinite-loading", V3InfiniteLoading.default);
app.mount("#app");
```

```css
#app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
  max-height: 400px;
  max-width: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.result {
  font-weight: 300;
  min-width: 400px !important;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #eceef0;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.37/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/v3-infinite-loading@1.0.6/lib/v3-infinite-loading.umd.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/v3-infinite-loading@1.0.6/lib/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="result" v-for="comment in comments" :key="comment.id">
      <div>{{ comment.email }}</div>
      <div>{{ comment.id }}</div>
    </div>
    <infinite-loading target="#app" @infinite="load"></infinite-loading>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are asking?
use `max-width` and `min-width`
These properties of CSS allows us to set `minimum width` values and `max width` values.

```js
const { ref, createApp } = Vue;
            const app = createApp({
                setup() {
                    let comments = ref([]);
                    let page = 1;
                    const load = async $state => {
                        console.log("loading...");
                        try {
                            const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?_limit=10&_page=" + page);
                            const json = await response.json();
                            if (json.length < 10) $state.complete();
                            else {
                                comments.value.push(...json);
                                $state.loaded();
                            }
                            page++;
                        } catch (error) {
                            $state.error();
                        }
                    };

                    return {
                        load,
                        comments,
                        page,
                    };
                },
            });
            app.component("infinite-loading", V3InfiniteLoading.default);
            app.mount("#app");
```

```css
#app {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                align-items: center;
                gap: 10px;
                padding: 20px;
                margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
                max-height: 400px;
                max-width: 500px;
                overflow-y: scroll;
            }
            .result {
                font-weight: 300;
                min-width: 400px;
        max-width: 400px;
                padding: 20px;
                text-align: center;
                background: #eceef0;
                border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: red;
            }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.37/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/v3-infinite-loading@1.0.6/lib/v3-infinite-loading.umd.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/v3-infinite-loading@1.0.6/lib/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <div class="result" v-for="comment in comments" :key="comment.id">
                <div>{{ comment.email }}</div>
                <div>{{ comment.id }}</div>
            </div>
            <infinite-loading target="#app" @infinite="load"></infinite-loading>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the `flex` shorthand property set the values of `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` & `flex-basis`. In your case, you would use `flex: 0 0 400px;`, therefore setting the `flex-basis`(the initial width that the flex child should take) to `400px`.

The reason why setting `width` doesn't work is that the `flex-grow:1; flex-shrink: 1; flex-basis: 0%;` properties are applied to the children of the flex container. **[Read more about it here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-property)**.

```js
const {
  ref,
  createApp
} = Vue;
const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    let comments = ref([]);
    let page = 1;
    const load = async $state => {
      console.log("loading...");
      try {
        const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?_limit=10&_page=" + page);
        const json = await response.json();
        if (json.length < 10) $state.complete();
        else {
          comments.value.push(...json);
          $state.loaded();
        }
        page++;
      } catch (error) {
        $state.error();
      }
    };

    return {
      load,
      comments,
      page,
    };
  },
});
app.component("infinite-loading", V3InfiniteLoading.default);
app.mount("#app");
```

```css
#app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
  max-height: 400px;
  max-width: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.result {
  font-weight: 300;
  /* width: 400px; */
  flex: 0 0 400px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #eceef0;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.37/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/v3-infinite-loading@1.0.6/lib/v3-infinite-loading.umd.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/v3-infinite-loading@1.0.6/lib/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="result" v-for="comment in comments" :key="comment.id">
      <div>{{ comment.email }}</div>
      <div>{{ comment.id }}</div>
    </div>
    <infinite-loading target="#app" @infinite="load"></infinite-loading>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```